# icon of a push notification GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I receive pushs notifications from my server correctly, but the showen icon in the bar is different from the icon's application, I don't know where this comming.

this is my code :

```
 private void sendNotification(String msg, String page_id) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("page_id", page_id);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setAutoCancel(false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

the application's icon in :

- res/drawable-hdpi  size : 72x72
- res/drawable-ldpi  size : 72x72
- res/drawable-mdpi  size : 48x48
- res/drawable-xhdpi size :96x6
- res/drawable-xxhdpi  size 144x144

Comment: what is the icon that shows up? A white square?

Comment: no icon from another application, even I remove it

Comment: `R.drawable.ic_launcher` this should appear. If you didnt changed your application icon it should be the android green head.

Comment: I see the icon of my application in left from R.drawable.ic_launcher, but when the notification arrive I see another icon.

Comment: You can try to change `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)` to another image source to see what will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my icon was in mipmap folder because, so when I change the directory from mimap to drawable it worked, thank's.